# PHP averiguar tamaño de consola de una conexion ssh

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un juego MOD en reactPHP (es un desafio personal). De momento estoy basandome en el ejemplo de chat que viene en la libreria socket (https://reactphp.org/socket/). En este caso, tengo la aplicacion que hace de servidor, y los clientes se conectan por telnet hacia el puerto 8080.

El problema consiste en que no se que tamaño de pantalla tiene el cliente. Puesto que es un juego de consola, esta pantalla dependerá de como tenga configurada la terminal/putty o el programa que utilice para conectar al servidor.

Por ejemplo,un cliente puede tener 80x25 caracteres. En linux podriamos verlo con:

```
echo $COLUMNSx$LINES
```

Pero que ocurre cuando estamos en una conexion remota? hay alguna manera de obtener ese tamaño? y lo mas dificil... se puede obtener en PHP?

Comment: Intenta ejecutar ese comando con `shell_exec()` y a ver si funciona. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php Por cierto, creo que si pones la `x` junto a `$COLUMNS` no va a funcionar. Sustitúyela por un espacio y luego parsea el resultado.

Comment: En este caso no devuelve valores. He probado shell-exec, exec y scapeshellcmd. Como tal, no esta definidas dichas variables de entorno. De todas formas, es una conexion telnet, es posible que la ejecucion de shell_exec devolviera los valores del servidor, y no del cliente.